# Как из приcвоить ImageSource объект Canvas из ResourceDictionary через код

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Я заполняю ListBox, который содержит картинку и имя, с помощью класса.
Как присвоить картинке Canvas из файла ресурсов и будет ли изменятся цвет этой картинке если изменять в Canvas'e заливку?

---

```
List<MenuListBoxItem> menuItems = new List<MenuListBoxItem>();        
ResourceDictionary iconDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
iconDictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Res/Vector/IconDictionary.xaml");       
menuItems.Add(new MenuListBoxItem("Search", (ImageSource)iconDictionary["appbar_radar"]));
```

---

```
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

    public class MenuListBoxItem
        {
            public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public MenuListBoxItem(string name, ImageSource image)
            {
                this.Image = image;
                this.Content = name;
            }
            public MenuListBoxItem(string name, Uri image)
            {
                this.Image = new BitmapImage(image);
                this.Content = name;
            }
            public MenuListBoxItem(string name, BitmapImage image)
            {
                this.Image = image;
                this.Content = name;
            }
        }
```

EDIT 1: В общем я пытаюсь получить такой вид меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы список брался из класса и цвет иконок мог меняться.
Код одной из иконок:

```
<Canvas x:Key="appbar_radar" x:Name="appbar_radar" Width="44" Height="44" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="42.4159" Height="44.3333" Canvas.Left="16.1674" Canvas.Top="15.8334" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource ContrastBrush}" Data="..."/>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: Что означает «присвоить картинке Canvas», простите? Что у вас картинка?

Comment: В ListBox есть картинка (Rectangle), я пытаюсь его свойству Fill присвоить такой вот Canvas из ResourceDictionary:
'<Canvas x:Key="appbar_radar" x:Name="appbar_radar" Width="44" Height="44" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="42.4159" Height="44.3333" Canvas.Left="16.1674" Canvas.Top="15.8334" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource ContrastBrush}" Data="..."/>
    </Canvas>'

Comment: Не-не, так работать не будет. У `Fill` какой тип? `Brush`. А у `Canvas` какой тип? Не `Brush`, и не совместим с `Brush`.

Comment: И `Rectangle` — это не картинка. `Image` — это картинка.

Comment: Ну и держать UI-элемент в `ResourceDictionary` не имеет особого смысла: вы не сможете «засунуть» его в более чем один элемент. У UI-элемента может быть только один предок.

Comment: Расскажите лучше (в вопросе), какого эффекта вы хотите достигнуть. Судя по всему, вы выбрали неправильный путь для этого.

Comment: Ага, понял. Я напишу немного позже.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотрите.

Один из центральных принципов WPF — разделение задач. Вы должны стараться не указывать UI-конструкции в описании ваших данных. Имеет смысл описывать в данных не то, какой UI у вашего элемента, а лишь необходимый минимум.

Кроме того, класть в `ResourceDictionary` куски UI неправильно. XAML — не просто «разметка», элементы создаются на самом деле, поэтому если вы кладёте визуальный фрагмент в него и используете в нескольких местах, вы получите ошибку. В качестве повторно используемых фрагментов уместно использовать различные `Template`'ы. Поскольку у вас повторяемая структура, уместно использовать `ItemTemplate`, а в параметр выносить часть, являющуюся чистыми данными, то есть `Geometry`.

В итоге получаем следующее:

XAML:

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Тест" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="SettingsIcon">M0,0 L0,1 L1,1 L1,0 z</StreamGeometry>
        <StreamGeometry x:Key="HelpIcon">M0,0 L1,1 M1,0 L0,1</StreamGeometry>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuColor">Green</SolidColorBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemDescriptor}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Path Data="{Binding Icon}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform"
                              Height="25" Width="25" Stroke="{DynamicResource MenuColor}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Grid.Column="1" Foreground="{DynamicResource MenuColor}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Понятно, что тут происходит? Мы изображаем последовательность одинаковых элементов, по одному на элемент коллекции, у каждого из них `Icon` и `Content` берётся из привязки.

Теперь code-behind:

Вспомогательный класс:

```
class ItemDescriptor
{
    public Geometry Icon { get; }
    public string Content { get; }

    public ItemDescriptor(Geometry icon, string content)
    {
        Icon = icon;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

И окно:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[]
        {
            new ItemDescriptor((Geometry)Resources["SettingsIcon"], "Settings"),
            new ItemDescriptor((Geometry)Resources["HelpIcon"], "Help"),
            new ItemDescriptor((Geometry)Resources["HelpIcon"], "Udp Multicast")
        };
    }
}
```

Нужный цвет фона и отступы добавить по вкусу.

---

Добавка для эстетов. Если вы хотите, чтобы класс `ItemDescriptor` не зависел от UI и не содержал `Geometry` (например, вы захотите передавать его из VM), нужна небольшая переделка. Во-первых, мы заменяем в `ItemDescriptor` `Icon` на `IconName`:

```
class ItemDescriptor
{
    public string IconName { get; }
    public string Content { get; }

    public ItemDescriptor(string iconName, string content)
    {
        IconName = iconName;
        Content = content;
    }
}
```

Соответственно, конструктор будет выглядеть проще:

```
        DataContext = new[]
        {
            new ItemDescriptor("SettingsIcon", "Settings"),
            new ItemDescriptor("HelpIcon", "Help"),
            new ItemDescriptor("HelpIcon", "Udp Multicast")
        };
```

Теперь XAML: в нём мы должны установить `DynamicResource`, а ключ взять из привязки! Из коробки `{DynamicResource ResourceKey={Binding Key}}` не работает, нам нужен вспомогательный класс.

Я пользуюсь таким трюком:

```
public class IndirectDynamicResource : FrameworkElement
{
    static IndirectDynamicResource()
    {
        WidthProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IndirectDynamicResource),
                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        HeightProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IndirectDynamicResource),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0));
        FocusableProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(IndirectDynamicResource),
                               new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));
    }

    #region object dp ResourceKey, change callback ValueUpdateCallback
    public object ResourceKey
    {
        get { return GetValue(ResourceKeyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ResourceKeyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ResourceKeyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "ResourceKey", typeof(object), typeof(IndirectDynamicResource),
            new PropertyMetadata(ValueUpdateCallback));
    #endregion

    static protected void ValueUpdateCallback(
            DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (IndirectDynamicResource)d;
        self.SetResourceReference(IndirectDynamicResource.ValueProperty,
                                  self.ResourceKey ?? string.Empty);
    }

    #region object dp Value
    public object Value
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(object), typeof(IndirectDynamicResource));
    #endregion
}
```

Имея это в арсенале, код в XAML меняем так:

```
<local:IndirectDynamicResource ResourceKey="{Binding IconName}" x:Name="D"/>
<Path Data="{Binding Value, ElementName=D}" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="Uniform"
      Height="25" Width="25" Stroke="{DynamicResource MenuColor}"/>
```

(Другие решения этой же проблемы см. [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20564862/276994).)

Всё!